# How to use JSON.NET correctly when deseralizing from embedded DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, embedded-resource, json.net, .net-assembly

I'm writing C# code in Visual Studio.  I add the embedded DLL inside the project, I am dynamically loading the assemblies.  We use JSON.NET to serialize and deserialize objects with type `Context.JobDataObj`, which is defined in one of the embedded DLLs, and passing the DLLs between various programs.

Unfortunately, whenever I attempt to deserialize, I get the following error:

> Type specified in JSON
>   'Context.JobDataObj, HPMContext,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible
>   with 'Context.JobDataObj, HPMContext,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

I'm looked up the error in the source code of JSON.NET, the error refers to `IsAssignableFrom` returning `false`...  When I move the DLL out of the project, the seralization and deseralization works like a charm.

UPDATED:

I've managed to pull in JSON.NET source code and debug it... apparently the only difference between whether it's using the embedded DLL and not is the return value of IsAssignableFrom in the line:

> if (objectType != null && !objectType.IsAssignableFrom(specifiedType))

`objectType` is equal in every way to `specifiedType`, I've checked all its assemblies, types, interfaces, members, etc etc.  Does anyone know how `IsAssignableFrom` determines it's values?

Comment: How exactly are you loading the embedded assembly?

Comment: Just wondering... why are you embedding the DLL? Could you use ilmerge instead to create a single assembly?

Comment: I'm using the assembly resolver + GetManifestResourceStream, the DLLs are being loaded correctly, follow by a Assembly.Load.

Comment: ILmerge has failed miserably for us because it tends to collapse/changes the namespace of the assembly, thus making the JSON scripts that generates contain incorrect values.  Nonetheless it has failed too often for us to go after bug after bug.