# Error when (de)serializing derived types with Json.Net

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to (de)serialize a class with this simple piece of code:-

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };

// Serialize
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);

// Deseralize - this is where it fails
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json, settings);
```

DeseralizeObject() fails with a JsonSerializationException:-

> Error resolving type specified in JSON 'Xxx.Common.MyObject, Xxx.Common'. Path '$type', line 1, position 110
>
> Inner exception: JsonSerializationException, message "Could not load assembly 'Xxx.Common".

I don't understand why it can't load the assembly - it's being referenced by this project!

It works if I don't use the `JsonSerializerSettings`, however I need this because the class being serialized will eventually have a `List<SomeBaseClass>` property that will contain derived types.

Any thoughts? I'm using Json.Net v6.0.

**Edit:**

I just tried adding `TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full` to my serializer settings, which resulted in this different (and confusing) exception message:-

> Type specified in JSON 'Xxx.Common.MyObject, Xxx.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible with 'Xxx.Common.MyObject, Xxx.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Path '$type', line 1, position 165.

**Edit2:**

To clarify things, the above code is a complete repro of the problem, and resides in a larger WPF application, while `MyObject` resides in a different project ("Xxx.Common") in the same solution, and is referenced by the WPF application project - I've simply replaced our company namespace with "Xxx" for this post.

MyObject is a simple POCO that I've created to rule out any issues that may be due to complex types, and consists of a few string and double properties, i.e.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Foo {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

The serialized JSON looks like this (again company NS replaced) - the pertinent part (i.e. the "$type") appears to be correct:-

> {"$type":"Xxx.Common.MyObject, Xxx.Common","Name":null,"Foo":0.0,"StepSize":0.0,"Convergence":0.0,"Cutoff":0.0}

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet please see Edit2 above.

Comment: Providing full structure of `MyObject` and the serialized data `json` will be helpful.

Comment: You claim "the above code is a complete repro of the problem" - it's clearly not. It's a snippet of code. A complete repro would be something we could copy, paste, compile and run - albeit in this case using multiple assemblies. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you [embedding DLLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934160/how-to-use-json-net-correctly-when-deseralizing-from-embedded-dll)?  Is there a chance you have an old version of the DLL (possibly from a different format (x86 vs x64)) in your path somewhere?  Could you have an old version of the DLL in the [GAC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324829/old-dlls-in-gac-are-still-being-used)?  See also [Old DLL file keeps being used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575253/old-dll-file-keeps-being-used).

Comment: @dbc I've tried serializing a class that lives in the same project as the code, and still get the problem. Interestingly moving the code out into a standalone repro project works fine, so the failure is down to some outside (non-code) factor. The code in my WPF application resides in an assembly that gets loaded dynamically using MAF, so I'm now thinking this may have something to do with it.

Comment: Json.NET's binder is [`DefaultSerializationBinder`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultSerializationBinder.cs).  You could make a local copy, set it in [`JsonSerializerSettings.Binder`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Binder.htm), and debug.  It would appear two copies of the DLL are getting loaded.  If you can create a full, reproducible example of the problem (including how you use MAF) we might be able to help more.